# Export GNotes via command line

Tags: command-line, console, gnote

Unfortunately it seems a recent system upgrade broke my graphics card driver, so I am going to hard-reinstall the latest Ubuntu Version (18.04). Before I do that, amongst other things, I want to export my GNotes. Due to the problem above I can only login via the console (Ctrl+Alt+F...), "and not GUI-wise".
What I'm asking for is maybe laid out in the official documentation https://help.gnome.org/users/gnote/unstable/plugins.html.en, but because I'm not really literate in this kind of computer stuff, could someone please lay out to me which sequence of commands I have to enter to store those as a html file in, say, my home directory?
In the GUI I know what to click to return my Library as pdf or html, but this way things are obviously trickier if not impossible.

Comment: Here is a script: https://github.com/rhoconlinux/gnote-massive-export-to-txt/blob/master/gnote-export-to-txt.sh

Comment: @Rinzwind [Please make that an answer!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281/507051)